# Sort entire Linked List into Ascending order based on String Value - Python

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to implement a Linked List in Python, and have been given this task of sorting it based on of the string values present in the Linked List.

I am trying to use the bubble sort logic and the below function is what I have come up with:

```
def sort_linked_list(self):
   
        temp = self.head_node

        if(temp == None) | (temp.next == None):
            return

        while(temp is not None):
            if(temp.song.song_name > temp.song.song_name):
                prev = temp
                temp = temp.next
                temp.next = prev
            temp = temp.next

        return
```

Unfortunately, this iterates over the first two values in my Linked List and is stuck in an infinite loop. I am pretty new to Linked List, hence might be making some fundamental mistake in this loop which I am unable to identify.

Any help is appreciated. Request to please add the explanation to the solution so that I can understand.

The code for the Linked List part:

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, song_id, song_name, song_length):
        self.song_id = song_id
        self.song_name = song_name
        self.song_length = song_length
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str({'song_id':self.song_id, 
                    'song_name':self.song_name, 
                    'song_length':self.song_length})
        

# Node for each of teh cong object that is going to be created. 
# Each of these node will contain the song data nd reference to the next element
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, song:Song):
        self.song = song
        self.next = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.song)
    

# Linked list class that will be used to do the various operations
# Insert, create, delete, traversal of the linked list
# Few other operation such as 
# a. deletion of song, 
# b. sorting a linked list based on song 
# c. randomly picking a song for playing

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_node = None
        self.count = 0
    
    # Traversing the linked lists
    def traversal(self):
        if self.head_node is None:
            return
        
        temp_node = self.head_node
        
        while(temp_node != None):
            print(temp_node.song)
            time.sleep(2)
            temp_node = temp_node.next
        
        time.sleep(2)
        
        return
    
    # insertion of the node in the beginning of the linked lists
    def insert_at_start(self, node):
        if self.head_node is None:
            self.head_node = node
            self.count = self.count + 1
            return True
        
        node.next = self.head_node
        self.head_node = node
        
        return True
    
    # insertion of the node after a particular song    
    def insert_after(self, song_name, node):
        temp_node = self.head_node
        
        # Checking till we find the song_name we are looking for
        while(temp_node.song.song_name!=song_name):
            temp_node = temp_node.next
          
        # if song is not found  
        if temp_node is None:
            return False

        # if song is found
        else:
            # Chckinhg if it is the last node
            if temp_node.next == None:
                temp_node.next = node
            # If it is not the last node
            else:
                node.next = temp_node.next
                temp_node.next = node
            
            return True
    
    # insertion of the node before a particular song in the linked lists    
    def insert_before(self, song_name, node):
        temp_node = self.head_node
        prev_node = None
        
        # Checking till we find the song_name we are looking for
        while(temp_node.song.song_name!=song_name):
            prev_node = temp_node
            temp_node = temp_node.next
        
        # if song is not found  
        if temp_node == None:
            return False

        # if list has only one song
        if prev_node == None:
            node.next = self.head_node
            self.head_node = node
            return True
        
        # updating the linked list and inserting the data
        prev_node.next = node
        node.next = temp_node
        
        return True
```

Comment: First of all to exchange nodes "temp" and "temp.next" you need access to the node which is before "temp" in the chain to change its "next" attribute.

Comment: Do you want to swap the *nodes* themselves, or the data inside the nodes?

Comment: i want to rearrange/sort the entire linkedlist based om the string value

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but there are two ways of doing that: either the nodes move to different places, but the strings remain with their nodes, **or**, the nodes stay where they are, but the string values they hold are swapped.

Comment: the nodes moving to different places is what i am looking for, however it would be great of you can share the other way as well. As I mentioned that I'm newbie in DSA bith the solutions would be great from knowledge pov. Tia!

Comment: What does your node class look like? Can you add its code?

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since this question does not provide the minimal code to reproduce the problem. It should define a Node class, a minimal(!) LinkedList class and driver code to populate a list and call this sort method.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the minimal code, let me know if you need more info on this!

Comment: Please add code that actually creates a list, populates it with nodes and then calls the sort function, so problem can be reproduced *and* a potential solution can be tested with the same driver code. And also: remove 2 of the 3 insertion methods. Surely the problem can be reproduced with a list that's built using just one insertion method.

Comment: Ugh! Sorting a linked list in place is horribly inefficient. It's easier, and more efficient, to create a new, sorted, list by traversing the current list and inserting each element in the appropriate position in the new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your attempt:

- The algorithm only makes one visit to every node. It is not possible to sort a list in just one sweep. Bubble sort needs two loops (nested). The outer loop keeps looping for as long as the inner loop had to make swaps. Once the inner loop does not find any pair to swap, the list is sorted, and the outer loop can stop.
- A swap of two adjacent nodes in general needs *two* references to change. The `next` attribute of the node that sits *before* that pair needs to be changed as well, and your code is not doing that.
- Sorting may mean that that what was originally the head node, no longer sits at the head, and so your code must foresee an assignment to `self.head_node`... or else the "sorted" version will always start with the *same* node as before the sort happened.

I would suggest to first create a dummy node that sits *before* the head node. This helps to simplify the code when the head node needs to be swapped. In that case the dummy's `next` attribute will change just like any other node's `next` can change. When all is done, we can then read what is the node that comes after the dummy, and make it the new head node.

```
    def sort_linked_list(self):
        sentinel = ListNode(None)
        sentinel.next = self.head_node
        
        dirty = True
        while dirty: # Repeat until the inner loop finds nothing to swap
            dirty = False
            node = sentinel
            # keep comparing the pair that follows after(!) `node`
            while node.next and node.next.next:
                first = node.next
                second = first.next
                if first.song.song_name > second.song.song_name:
                    # A swap needs to set two(!) next attributes
                    node.next = second
                    first.next = second.next
                    second.next = first
                    dirty = True  # Indicate that the outer loop needs another iteration
                node = node.next
        
        # Make sure the head node references the right node after sorting
        self.head_node = sentinel.next
```

Here is a demo which quickly creates a few nodes with your classes and then runs the above method and finally traverses the sorted list:

```
# Your code without change, except in the `sort_linked_list` method
class Song:
    def __init__(self, song_id, song_name, song_length):
        self.song_id = song_id
        self.song_name = song_name
        self.song_length = song_length
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str({'song_id':self.song_id, 
                    'song_name':self.song_name, 
                    'song_length':self.song_length})
        

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, song:Song):
        self.song = song
        self.next = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.song)
    

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_node = None
        self.count = 0
    
    def traversal(self):
        if self.head_node is None:
            return
        temp_node = self.head_node
        while(temp_node != None):
            print(temp_node.song)
            temp_node = temp_node.next
        return
    
    def insert_at_start(self, node):
        if self.head_node is None:
            self.head_node = node
            self.count = self.count + 1
            return True
        node.next = self.head_node
        self.head_node = node
        return True
    
    def sort_linked_list(self):
        sentinel = ListNode(None)
        sentinel.next = self.head_node
        
        dirty = True
        while dirty: # Repeat until the inner loop finds nothing to swap
            dirty = False
            node = sentinel
            # keep comparing the pair that follows after(!) `node`
            while node.next and node.next.next:
                first = node.next
                second = first.next
                if first.song.song_name > second.song.song_name:
                    # A swap needs to set two(!) next attributes
                    node.next = second
                    first.next = second.next
                    second.next = first
                    dirty = True  # Indicate that the outer loop needs another iteration
                node = node.next
        
        # Make sure the head node references the right node after sorting
        self.head_node = sentinel.next


# Demo 
titles = [
    "Smells Like Teen Spirit",
    "Billie Jean",
    "Stayin’ Alive",
    "I Will Survive",
    "Whole Lotta Love",
    "Sweet Child O’Mine",
    "Scream and Shout",
    "Santeria",
    "Alright",
    "Thrift Shop"
]

lst = LinkedList()
for i, title in enumerate(titles):
    lst.insert_at_start(ListNode(Song(i, title, len(title))))
lst.sort_linked_list()
lst.traversal()  # Outputs the 10 songs in sorted order
```

Comment: Initially I have 10 nodes in my linked list, but when I run this code, it returns only 2 nodes, but they are sorted in ascending order

Comment: This works fine for me on a list with 10 nodes. I think your surrounding code may have problems. Can you edit your question and add the definition of your Node class and the insert/add method on your LinkedList class? (I already asked this before -- below your question -- but you didn't reply)

Comment: Well, while you consider updating your question, here is a demo running the above code on 10 nodes: [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma728169015459839)

Comment: Sorry, but the question should have all necessary information embedded in the question, not behind a link. This requires some work from your part, as you must provide *minimal* code to reproduce the problem. So any code that is not related to the question should not be included. I will delete my answer

Comment: Undeleted my answer, and added a block with your class code, the corrected sort method, and my driver code added to it to demonstrate it really works.